# Scheduling a cron job to run a shell scipt and select options

Tags: shell, cron

Following are the option on executing a tool `appTool`

```
========================
+      Operations      +
========================
  (1) Quick Test
  (2) Help
  (3) Exit
========================
```

I want to check if the script is running and execute it if it is not running, I have created the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

service=appTool
checkRunning=`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l > 0`

echo $checkRunning

if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
        echo "$service is running!!!"
else
        1| /etc/init.d/$service start
fi
```

When the script is executed I wish to pass the option `1` when the job is scheduled.

How can this be achieved ??